# What type of test do I use?

Tags: ancova

I have created 39 question Likert scale survey and want to cross-reference results with 5 demographic questions.  I plan on assigning values for each answer 1=strongly disagree, 2=disagree, 3=neutral, etc.  I am required to put info into SPSS.  I am rather confused on which test I should use: ANOVA, ANCOVA etc.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly is "cross-reference?" Correlation? Group differences? And what the five demographics? Are you going to perform 5*39 = 195 tests? Or are you planning to lump the 39 up in a certain way? And lastly, what is the reason of putting "Neutral" at the last? That does not sound like [Likert's scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) to me. And sorry for machine gunning you with questions, word limit is to blame. I am a lot nicer when I am not typing comments.

Comment: I appreciate your response! The 39 questions are all the same for all subjects.  Demographics include age, income, ethnicity, and education level.  My answers to the survey are strongly agree, agree, nuetral, disagree, Strongly disagree. I was hoping to see if there was a correlation between responses and each of the 5 demographics. you helped me to realize I don't want to do 195 tests

Comment: Basically, I want to see if parents are understanding a program we are running in a school.  I do not have to do demographics. However - I have a theory (Yikes) that most parents haven't a clue what we are asking. I Just want to know whether or not they understand and back it up in a statistical format.

Comment: Are all 39 questions measuring the same latent variable, are they mostly unrelated to one another, or is the theoretical structure more complex than either of these? Are you concerned with controlling for relationships with other variables while measuring the relationship between any two? Are you actually interested in the relationships, or are you trying to decide whether you can ignore them by testing the "significance" of your results against a null of zero difference and a conventional threshold? I suppose I should apologize for machine-gunning too ;) There are a lot of issues to decide!

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you want to do MANOVA (multiple anova's) in SPSS, i.e. to see if there is a significant difference between the mean response in each of the 39 questions between the different demographics. The problem, as Penguin_Knight specifies, is that you are not posing any hypothesis for testing and as such you are doing 195 tests.

This requires corrections to the confidence level, which can be very conservative and will reduce your power to a great degree (i.e. Type II errors). Hopefully you have multiple scales measuring a few constructs, and this won't be as big of an issue.

Comment: Your info is very helpful - and appreciated.  I can't help but wonder if I should not compare demographics with survey responses but just use an ANOVA to look at - simply put - the responses.  I want to keep it simple - THoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking: ANOVA works by, for instance, comparing the mean of caucasians (categorical) to the mean (on one item in your questionnaire) of the overall sample. If you want to compare the means between two different items, you are talking about something else - it would help if you were more specific about what your 'research question' is.